# Sitecore glass mapper general link in Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, glass-mapper

Hi i'm currently learning sitecore 7 with MVC4 and glassmapper and I'm having some issues with the general linkfield. I can't seem to ouput the external links (not links to items) correctly from a general linkfield. What am I doing wrong?

My model:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{F8168BAF-6916-47FE-BC7F-DE3B033CE233}")]
public class SocialLink : AbstractBase
{

    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Class { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
    public virtual Link Url { get; set; }

}
```

in the view:

```
@foreach (var socialLink in Model.SocialFolder.Socials)
{
     <a href="@socialLink.Url" class="connect @socialLink.Class">@socialLink.Description</a>                
}
```

Output:

```
<a href="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link" class="connect slideshare">Read us on Slideshare</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the model auto-generated or did you create them manually? What type is Link, `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link`? If so you need `@socialLink.Url.Url`, you want the Url property from the Link field called Url.

```
@foreach (var socialLink in Model.SocialFolder.Socials)
{
     <a href="@socialLink.Url.Url" class="connect @socialLink.Class">@socialLink.Description</a>                
}
```

I would be very tempted to rename `Class` and `Url` properties to something else, possibly `CssClass` and `SocialMediaUrl` or something so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: The model is manually created. With the '.url' behind it is working. thanks for that and I will change the names to stop confusion.

To further enhance this, do you know what the best is way to create an editable link field for the page editor?

Comment: @FilipHuysmans You should just use a single LinkField, there is no need for `Description` or `Class` since you can set those can be [set in the properties of the link](http://i.imgur.com/vSyCkLX.png). Then you can make the field [Editable in Glass](http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial05/tutorial05.html)

Comment: I've tried something else:
@RenderLink(socialLink, x=>x.Url, new NameValueCollection {{"class", "connect " + socialLink.Class}}, true, contents: socialLink.Description)
But when isEditable is set to true, it is not showing up in the page editor. The field is just invisible but on normal mode everything works. When I delete the contents parameter it works in the page editor. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @FilipHuysmans Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587981/how-to-render-link-with-css-class-with-sitecore-glass-mapper

Comment: Do you know how I can use a different field as the description of the link. I can only use the description from the link field with: @(Editable(socialLink, x => x.Url,new {@class=String.Format("connect {0}", socialLink.Class)}))  and I can't use the page editor with: @(RenderLink(socialLink, x=>x.Url, new NameValueCollection {{"class", "connect " + socialLink.Class}},true, socialLink.Description))

Comment: `@(Editable<YourModelType>(Model, x => x.Link, string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">{1}</a>", x.Link.Url, x.Link.Text)))` from the link I gave you didn't work? Otherwise no, I don't know any other way than using just the Link field as I suggested - which makes sense this is control editor that Sitecore provides, how do you tell it which parts of the link should be saved to which field?

Comment: It works if I just use the general link field without any additional fields. With the sc:Link field I was able to combine a link field with other fields and make everything editable but this seems not to be possible in mvc with glass mapper. Thanks for your advice on this matter!

Comment: [Mike Edwards](https://twitter.com/mikeedwards83) is probably best able to answer, I'm not sure myself. You could try messaging him.

Answer (score 1):

So that Anchors and Querystrings are supported, it's best to use `link.BuildUrl((SafeDictionary<string>)null)`

There are two `Link.BuildUrl()`methods and, annoyingly, they both have default parameters (although one marked as obsolete). You will need to specify which one via a typed null, or...

You can add an extension method which will make things easier

```
public static class GlassFieldExtensions
{
    public static string GetUrl(this Link link)
    {
        return link.BuildUrl(null as SafeDictionary<string>);
    }
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
@foreach (var socialLink in Model.SocialFolder.Socials)
{
     <a href="@socialLink.GetUrl()" class="connect @socialLink.Class">@socialLink.Description</a>                
}
```